# Make div below first div to right of first div when responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two Divs, Div A and Div B with Div A is above Div B, How do I write bootstrap code so that when the site is made responsive both the divs should be aligned in same line?

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <div id="div_A">
        </div> 
        <div id="div_B">
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
         <!-- some content --> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: PLease put your code here

Comment: Here is my code... I want Div A and Div B one below other when I see on PC, and side by side when I view the same on Tablets or mobiles.....Please Help.....Thanks

Comment: <div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="div_A"></div>
  <div id="div_B"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <!-- some content -->
 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking to this kind of markup?

```
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
```

If yes using class like this will do the job.

```
<div id="A" class="col-md-12 col-lg-6"></div>
<div id="B" class="col-md-12 col-lg-6"></div>
```